# API Usage Page title is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, title

If you look at the [API 1.1 Usage page](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage) on any SE network site it is titled as `API Usage - Audio Recording and Meta API`.  If you look on any [1.0 usage page](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/usage) it is titled `API Usage - Stack Overflow API` (which isn't totally correct either, but is at least understandable).

Perhaps it should be titled `API Usage - Stackexchange API` for simplicity, or correctly title the site.

Comment: I think the one page [you linked](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage) is actually correct, `<title>API Usage - Stack Overflow Api</title>` (capitalization aside...). But indeed, [others](http://api.superuser.com/1.1/usage) are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meh, its weird to include the conceptual "site title" on the documentation, as its the same thing for all sites.

Just stripped that out for the API docs.